# Place a static block at the right side of the logo

Tags: magento, static

I want to place a static block just after the logo at the right side of it but my static block is in the upper or lower position, I have added the block from `1coloum.xml` page.

Comment: Please ask your question in more detail use screenshot or code sample

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the following code in theme header.phtml after the logo.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('example_block_id')->toHtml();
```

then you may need to change some css.